# Retrieving an array of Documents from mongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection containing documents of employees. Each employee have an array of documents with the projects this employee is currently involved in. The problem is that i don't know how to get/query the array of projects?

Here is an example of such document.

```
{name : "employe name" , age : "..employe age" , phoneNr : 12334 , projects : 
[{ projectName : "project name" , projectLeder : "project leader" }] }
```

Here is an example code for retrieving the values in the document except the project array.

```
public void printEmployees() {

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = coll.find().iterator();

        while(cursor.hasNext()) {

            Document documentEmployee = cursor.next();
            System.out.println((String) documentEmployee.get("name"));
            System.out.println((Integer) documentEmployee.get("age"));
            System.out.println((Integer) documentEmployee.get("phoneNr"));
            //How do i query/extract the project array?

        }  

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
   Document documentEmployee = cursor.next();
   System.out.println(documentEmployee.getString("name"));
   System.out.println(documentEmployee.getInteger("age"));
   System.out.println(documentEmployee.getInteger("phoneNr"));
   //Extract
   ArrayList projects = documentEmployee.get("project", ArrayList.class);
   //Map
   for (Object obj : projects) {
         Document project = (Document) obj;
         project.getString("projectName");
   }
}
```